# Taking 'n' space separated integers in Python, storing in matrix and print the matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, user-input

I want to take `n` space separated integers and storing in a matrix and then print the matrix.
I am using **Python 3.7**.

My code is:

```py
size = int(input("\nEnter number of rows or colums: ")) #square matrix

#Define the matrix
matrix = []
print("\nEnter the entries:")

#for user input
for row in range(size):     
    temp = []
    for column in range(size):      
        temp.append(int(input()))
    matrix.append(temp)


#To print the matrix
print("\nThe matrix is :")
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        print(matrix[i][j], end="\t")
    print()
```

I can only able to take input like this

```
Enter number of rows or colums: 2

Enter the entries:
1
2
3
4

The matrix is :
1       2
3       4
```

but I want to take input like this

```
Enter number of rows or colums: 2

Enter the entries:
1 2
3 4

The matrix is :
1       2
3       4
```

If I try to take space separated integers and then press Enter for the new line I get this below error massage

```
Enter number of rows or colums: 2

Enter the entries:
1 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/Python/matrix.py", line 12, in <module>
    temp.append(int(input()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2'
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `.split()` on an input row. For example `'1 2'.split()` is the list `['1', '2']`

Comment: @JohnColeman I try to use this but I had to take double times input in that case. Like I had to take 4 rows whereas I need 2 rows. This problem occurs.

Comment: Don't use `input` in a nested loop? You don't have to loop over the individual entries if you don't want to. If you are familiar with list comprehensions, `[int(i) for i in intput().split()]` is useful.

Comment: @JohnColeman Your `[int(i) for i in input().split()]` this line solved all of my problems. I have also understood my problem. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated code:

```
size = int(input("\nEnter number of rows or colums: ")) #square matrix

#Define the matrix
matrix = []
print("\nEnter the entries:")

#for user input
for row in range(size):
    # Read row, space separated value
    matrix.append(
        [int(n) for n in input().split(' ')]
    )

#To print the matrix
print("\nThe matrix is :")
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        print(matrix[i][j], end="\t")
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks for this amazing answer bro. I just don't want to print `Row 0:`, `Row 1:` etc. Can you change this line `[int(n) for n in input('Row {}:'.format(row)).split(' ')]` from your code to fixed this. All of my problems will be solved.